# 301 Moved Permanently when running EventSource in express server

Tags: node.js

I am running an Server Side Events with EventSource. While running my localhost it works just fine. But when I run the app from server i am seeing **301 Moved Permanently** when the event is fired with below URL.

Local URL: Works fine
http://localhost:8000/myposts/sse?Acct=12344545455656

Website URL: Getting error as 301 Moved Permanently.
https://www.example.com/myposts/sse?Acct=12344545455656

I am running the above using KrakenJS. Any pointers or help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the `Location` header of the 301 response contain?

Comment: I see the location as https://www.example.com/webapp/home which is different app running

Comment: It looks like your app may be using some sort of middleware that is generating that redirect, or you are using a reverse proxy that is configured incorrectly. Difficult to determine which without more information.